# how to bevel quarter cylinder (only vertical edges)

Tags: bevel

I'm wondering how to properly round the vertical edges of a quarter of a cylinder as in the screenshot:
[image: bevel]

Red shows how the bevel tool works.
As expected it doesn't work well where the big face meets the arc (small face)

Thank in advance for help.

Comment: Apply the scale to your object using Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode and try again!

Answer (score 2):

You are not gonna be able to do that if the curved part of the cylinder has all those faces. At least not with stock blender (You can with the MeshMachine Addon, but it's paid)
To do something like this in stock Blender you can use a subdivided mesh instead of a cylinder with many faces.
[image]
Use something with low enough faces that they let you room for the bevel. 32 seem close to what you want. You can then put a subdivision modifier on the object and mart the top and bottom edges as Crease so they remain sharp. Then just place some edges around the bevel are to contain the bevel like in the picture.
The smoothing effect of the subdivision modifier will give you that round edge

Answer (score 2):

Select the edges that you want to Bevel and set the Bevel Weight in the sidebar to 1.

Now in the Modifier, change the limit method to Weight.

[image]

[image]

[image]